# Programmatically Set Timestamp on Commit?

Tags: libgit2

I would like to use libgit2 to create commits with specific timestamps, OTHER than the current system time.  How is this done?

Answer (score 3):

Use `git_signature_new()` to create the author and/or committer signatures (ie. name + email + date + offset to UTC).

Pass those signatures to `git_commit_create()`.

**References:**

- **[git_signature_new()](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/signature/git_signature_new)** documentation
- **[git_commit_create()](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/commit/git_commit_create)** documentation
- **[Sample usage](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/89c332e41b12a72d89de40d63bc568c56a2c336a/tests/revwalk/basic.c#L456-L459)** from the **[tests](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/tree/master/tests)**